# How to set up half minute hero to display gamepad buttons instead of keyboard keys?

Tags: pc, half-minute-hero

I use a gamepad, but the game is trying to be smart by displaying the keyboard keys as tooltips. How can this be changed?

Comment: Is your gamepad plugged in as you launch the game? (Is it the XBox gamepad?)

Comment: @badp Yes it is. Apparently I'm not the only one bugged by this: http://steamcommunity.com/app/214830/discussions/0/882961586639965092/. It's not an XBox gamepad, if that matters, it's a BigBen one (with the same button colors).

Answer (score 2):

Go into controls, and click "Key Config". Then hit left/right at the top (settings)

Then hit "A".